Web page query in QGIS
Is it possible to query the website in QGIS? In other words, I make inquiries on the internet by entering data such as province, district and neighbourhood. I want to do this as if it were a module in QGIS. In summary, I want to query a collective area by taking data from the cadastral information system.

Do you want do this like a search feature in Google Maps or programmatically for multiple entries?

Can you be more precise in your question? Are you trying to develop a plugin? What result do you expect (webpages, geodata)?

A web-based cadastral information system is available. I want to download shp data from this system by selecting a bulk area, that is, by creating a buffer zone. But I don't know/couldn't find if I can do this in QGIS or if there is something similar. or you can query by entering province, district, neighborhood, island-parcel information.

Sorry, without a link to the webpage of the cadastral information system, it's impossible to help. You might have a look if there is a plugin available for this site/service.

The job I want has applications made with PHP. but I have no idea how to do this in QGIS. Website, API etc. there is.

If I understood you correctly, you want to search placename in QGIS in the same way as in Webmaps like OpenStreetMap, Google maps etc. and the map should zoom to the relevant location.
To do so, go to the Locator Bar (bottom left in your QGIS window) insert > followed by a space and the placename you searach. E.g. > Paris.
This activates Nominatim Geocoder and you get a selection of places that correspond to the text you entered. Double click one and the map jumps/zooms to this place:


I want to query the query screen of the cadastral database in bulk using QGIS and obtain those fields in shape format.

Sorry, your question is unclear. Please edit your initial post and post links to the sites/ressources you want the query to apply.
